# Loop over aliases in Bash

Tags: bash, alias

I have a couple of `aliases` defined in `~/.bash_aliases`. They call the same command with different settings of environment variables so I do not have to type these in every time. The `aliases` work fine in interactive shells.

```
alias cmd1='VAR=setting1 cmd $@'
alias cmd2='VAR=setting2 cmd $@'
```

Now I would like to call all of these commands variants together, each one with the option "list". For this purpose I have set up the following script in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases
CMDs='cmd1 cmd2'
for cmd in CMDs ; do
    $cmd list
done
```

However, this script yields the error

> "command not found"

for each `alias` called. I have tried all kind of variants but do not see how the internals of Bash work here. -- Any insights welcome!

Comment: Thanks for your help with formatting my post, @Cyrus!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aliases don't take arguments. What's happening is that `$@` expands to *nothing* when you define the alias, so it behaves exactly the same as `alias cmd1='VAR=setting1 cmd '`. The "arguments" are simply appended to the expansion of the alias.

Define functions instead:

```
cmd1 () {
    VAR=setting1 cmd "$@"
}

cmd2 () {
    VAR=setting2 cmd "$@"
}
```

Further, alias expansion happens *before* parameter expansion, which explains the error you are seeing. Once `$cmd` expands to `cmd1`, `bash` doesn't try to expand `cmd1` as an alias; it just treats it as the name of a command it cannot find. Function lookup happens once all expansions are applied, so your loop

```
CMDs='cmd1 cmd2'
source ~/.bash_aliases
for cmd in CMDs ; do
  "$cmd" list
done
```

will now work. `cmd1` is found to be a function, and so executes with `list` as its argument. (You may want to store the functions in a file with a different name, but it doesn't really matter. Despite the name, `.bash_aliases` just has to be a valid script, not just a collection of aliases.)

Comment: Many thanks for sharing your knowledge, #chepner! Missing information from my point of view was that "alias expansion happens before parameter expansion". Your very detailed solution makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias xxx="printf '%s\n'"
alias yyy="echo"
for cmd in xxx yyy
do
    eval $cmd foo bar bla
done
```

**ATTENTION** `eval` is a beast and quite insecure. Look to the [Bash FAQ 048](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this complementary solution, @A.H. As it looks so straightforward, I appreciate the additional call for caution.